# Is it okay if you rely heavily in your proposal on information that you got from a PhD thesis rather than a well known book by a well known author?

Tags: phd, citations, thesis, advisor, research-proposal

Would potential supervisors be concerned about whether my main source is credible enough?
(this is for a PhD in Literature)

Answer (score 7):

I think that **using another PhD thesis** as a reference **is not a problem** at all.

I am certainly sure that **using ONLY another PhD thesis** as a reference **is a big problem**.

---

I am not aware of the specific requirements for PhD theses in literature, in general, and your institution, in particular. However, I am quite certain that if a "main source" qualification could be attached to one particular reference—this might be a sign of weaker research, at least in this limited aspect.

Thus, no matter what (other PhD theses, books, journal papers, etc) you are considering to be sources\references for a particular subtopic of your thesis, I would encourage using several of them and discussing what each brings to the picture.

I would also look into what sources\references are used in the thesis that you intend to cite and consider whether they might be relevant to your research.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence. That will be a check on the reliability of the thesis too.

Comment: This is exactly why I'm asking. The PhD thesis is referring to an issue which it says exists in many well-know books. I can't go read all those books now. I'll have to rely on the PhD author's word, use it to write a proposal, and then if the proposal is accepted, only then I will have the time and money to read all those books and check.

Comment: @Amin that depends on the definition of the "proposal". In many countries, proposal is the work that is done usually in the second or third year of your graduate program. In this case, I would say, you should read a bit more in depth besides ONE PhD thesis. However, if the proposal is done before you joined any supervisor as an idea for the research, you have more lenience on doing a less thorough literature review.